# composite EditText using drawable as side icon

Tags: android, android-layout

My problem is there isn't any rounded corner at the left bottom region of the rectangular, even though I defined it as 10dp.

Is there a better way to put a Drawable next to the EditText, rather than using my silly approach ?
Or how can my approach be redefined ?

Excerpt from the layout:

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/email_bordered"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:paddingLeft="34dp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    /><EditText
```

The email_bordered.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- This controls the white background-->
    <item
        android:width="32dp"
        android:height="90dp"
        android:left="1.9dp"
        android:bottom="1.9dp"
        >

        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
                />
            <solid android:color="#fff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- This adds the vector image -->
    <item
        android:bottom="50dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_if_mail_461377"
        android:gravity="left">

    </item>

    <!-- This draws the border around everything -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#ffffff"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="10dp"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>




</layer-list>
```

And this is the preview:
[image: drawable preview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `drawableLeft` tag within the EditText to get the desired design.

```
 <EditText
...     
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_if_mail_461377"
android:drawablePadding="10dp"/>
```

**EDIT**

With a few changes in the `layer-list`, the final outcome is something like this.

[image]

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="45dp"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/pic"
android:drawablePadding="10dp"
android:background="@drawable/email_bordered"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
android:paddingLeft="4dp"
android:textSize="30sp"
/>
```

email_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- This controls the white background-->
<item
    android:width="62dp"
    android:height="45dp"
    android:left="1.9dp"
    android:bottom="1.9dp"
    >

    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topRightRadius="0dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
            />
        <solid android:color="#fff" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- This adds the vector image -->



<!-- This draws the border around everything -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:width="1.9dp"
            android:color="#ffffff"/>
        <corners
            android:radius="10dp"
            />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Ok, the drawable icon looks fine, but I still need to have the borders around the EditText :)

Comment: Please check the edited answer. I have added the outcome design also.

Comment: Look great, but there is a white space width as two of the icons, its both in the preview and the real device. Somehow your example image doesn't match mine :(.

Comment: I think the image used by you is not a PNG with transparent background. [This](http://userscontent2.emaze.com/images/48291eb0-1b08-4b43-b779-1432067cf0ca/60ed9735-d387-4c95-a5ee-3ad35ae64928.png) is the image I have used for the example.

Comment: The image I use is a vector drawable, and I think I fixed by shrinking the android:width="32dp"

Comment: Oh I see. Glad to help! Cheers!